# Basement Footer Removal

Tags: bathroom, foundation, footings

This is kind of a convoluted situation, and I hope it isn't too confusing.

I just bought a home with my wife, and in the basement there was a hideous bathroom.  Functional, but hideous.  So I am tearing it out and remodeling as a DIY project.

The vanity, was clearly made by the home owner and was basically a bunch of plywood boards screwed together.  It was a little strange looking.  After tearing it apart, I found out why.

It looks like at one point, they removed one of the concrete block (interior) walls and replaced it with a couple metal columns and steel I-beams.  They did however leave the poured concrete footer, and the vanity was built around that.  I have a few questions that I was hoping I could get opinions on.

1. Why would they go through all the trouble of removing the block wall, but not jack hammer away the footer?  Am I wrong in my assessment?  I would provide pictures but I am away from home on travel.  I could get my wife to take some if need be though.
2. Is there any reason why I shouldn't jack hammer away this footer?  For the bathroom remodel, I could use the foot and a half or so of extra space.  I am going to get a structural engineer out here, but I wanted some opinions from here first.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I found out and ended up doing.

To answer my own questions:

1. Because removing a block (not filled in) wall is MUCH easier than getting rid of the footer.  I got some waterproofing contractors down there to install waterproofing and had them try to remove this footer with their jackhammers.  It became immediately clear that it would have taken FOREVER and would have been extremely messy and difficult.  This is solid concrete about 2 foot thick.
2. The reason is because it would have been very labor intensive.  Structurally there was nothing actually on top of the footer so it likely would have been fine to get rid of it (although if I did end up going this route, I still would have called someone in to assess).

What I ended up doing was building around it.  I put a linen closet on that wall.  The floor of the closet goes to the top of this footer.  It actually ended up looking really nice and was also convenient because you don't need to bend down to get things on the closet floor.

Comment: Glad this worked out for you! Please be sure to give yourself a check mark as soon as the system will let you!

Answer (score 0):

They removed a portion of an exterior basement wall...maybe because, 1) started a remodel/addition and then changed their minds, 2) discovered something outside the wall that changed their minds, 3) noticed remaining walls starting to “move” and stopped project.

Yes, I’d get a structural engineer (not a civil engineer) to review.

You must live in a dry area if there’s no moisture problems with the wall gone, but I’d have him examine that too.

BTW, I’d be shocked if the structural engineer recommends removing the footing.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear.  This was an interior wall that looked to tie into the exterior wall.

Comment: Ahhh...the remaining footing is being used to support the load transferred by the steel beam. That is to say, the load that was originally transferred to the footing through the wall is now transferred by the beam to the footing. If you remove the footing, you’ll need to construct an equivalent amount of footing on each side of the opening.